# Map interface to intersection type

Tags: typescript

Given an interface `A` such as the following, we imagine an external service that provides a lookup function to return each value.

```js
interface A {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}
```

Plainly, the external service `S` would look like this:

```js
interface S {
    get(name: 'a'): string;
    get(name: 'b'): number;
    get(name: 'c'): boolean;
}
```

But how would one express this as a generic type construct `S<A>` – ?

Perhaps we can start by observing that the following declaration is functionally identical to the one above:

```js
type S = {
    get: ((name: 'a') => string) & ((name: 'b') => number) & ((name: 'c') => boolean))
}
```

This would be used like so:

```js
const c = service.get('c');  // 'c' would be type boolean here.
```

I have tried building from `keyof A` and using the following helper to move from union to intersection:

```js
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never
```

But this is where I'm stuck. Help!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAygPAQQHxQLxQN4CgpQOYTBwDSUEAHsBAHYAmAzlANYQgD2AZlMgBTUCGAWwgAuKMQCUYhAG1iAXQDcWAL7KsAS2pUATh34BjaAkw4o-MfWA6teZbgBGY6gFdBDiDvtQDYh2zYAGwh+amUVLCxQSCgAJQh6F0DgNFhEJHUDNmorKHpPADcNI1SMFXNGeMTkzOzc-lT8nSKjADoCYB4Acn4uiSgAegG861ssLJyUh0bC4oh2wm6HPsHh13dPcbqUgxnmuYXOroMVoah-IJDqIA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: I don't know *why* you don't want to "resort" to generics... obviously use cases will drive whether you want generics or overloads, but overloads are known to have their own issues.

Comment: @wonderflame that looks great and seems to work perfectly, very succinct.

Comment: @jcalz yeah that phrasing made no sense, I have removed that bit in my question, it was supposed to help with the narrative but just ended up confusing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jcalz mentioned, the single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) method would be much easier and more concise. We will create `S` accepting the `A` type and will add a generic method that will accept another generic parameter that will be constrained to be the `A`'s key and by using *indexed access* we will get the correct type:

```
type S<A> = {
  get<K extends keyof A>(name: K): A[K];
};
```

Testing:

```
type Result = S<A>;

const service = {} as Result;

const a = service.get('a') // string
const b = service.get('b') // number
const c = service.get('c') // boolean
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAygPAQQHxQLxQN4CgpQOYTBwDSUEAHsBAHYAmAzlANYQgD2AZlMgBTUCGAWwgAuKMQCUYhAG1iAXQDcWAL7KsAS2pUATh34BjaAkw4o-MfWA6teZbgBGY6gFdBDiDvtQDYh2zYAGwh+amUVLCxQSCgAJQh6F0DgNFhEJHUDNmorKHpPADcNI1SMFXNGeMTkzOzc-lT8nSKjADoCYB4Acn4uiSgAegG861ssLJyUh0bC4oh2wm6HPsHh13dPcbqUgxnmuYXOroMVoah-IJDqIA)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we really do want a list of [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) instead of a single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) method, you can write `S<T>` like this:

```
type S<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (x: { get(name: K): T[K] }) => void
} extends Record<string, (x: infer I) => void> ? I : never
```

which uses the same basic approach as in [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218) to convert each desired piece to the parameter of a function, so that [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) produces an intersection:

```
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
}

type SA = S<A>;
/* type SA = {
    get(name: "a"): string;
} & {
    get(name: "b"): number;
} & {
    get(name: "c"): boolean;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.3.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgLmQGcwpQBzAbh2QCNCQBXAW1umtwUNoHseAbCHBDUAvlixgAngAcUAZQA8AFQB8yALyYaAbQDSyUMgDWEKTxjJlAXUIAKAB6EMychDB2QcZhEJ6AlITK+tbIov6a6gBuPMAAJliiyBAOkCBxRMgAShAIPFBxiiRkIOQANMiOhKAw0MgAkhEa0bFx6gD8DcgMEFHQEtJyyPLoWkqoqtQA9ABUyIMKo9q4uG4eXj6EAERwW4HEpBRiyABkyytrnt6+yFu0ewwsbFDHZ9grru5Xm7cID3R8QTCY4zKYSIA)

Comment: I would mark this as the answer, but actually wouldn't you agree that the generics approach outlined in the question comments is a more elegant solution?

Comment: I would agree but you explicitly mentioned not “resorting to generics” so I assumed you really wanted overloads for some reason.  I’m not offended if you accept another answer though.